# Cambiar menu con frameset a bootstrap

Tags: html, asp.net, bootstrap

tengo un sitio web en la cual el front esta dividido con frameset, de esta manera:

```
<FRAMESET name="fstMain" cols="*,980,*" border="0" frameborder="0" TOPMARGIN="0" LEFTMARGIN="0"
    MARGINHEIGHT="0" MARGINWIDTH="0" frameSpacing="0" onload="redirLocation();">
    <FRAME name="blanco" src="inicio.htm" scrolling="no" border="0" frameborder="no" noresize
        TOPMARGIN="0" LEFTMARGIN="0" MARGINHEIGHT="0" MARGINWIDTH="0">
    <FRAMESET id="fraMain" rows="102,*" border="0" FRAMESPACING="0" TOPMARGIN="0"
        LEFTMARGIN="0" MARGINHEIGHT="0" MARGINWIDTH="0">
        <FRAME name="fraToolbar" src="header.aspx" scrolling="no" border="0" frameborder="no" noresize
            TOPMARGIN="0" LEFTMARGIN="0" MARGINHEIGHT="0" MARGINWIDTH="0">
        <FRAMESET name="fstMain" cols="200,*" border="0" frameborder="0" FRAMESPACING="0" TOPMARGIN="0"
            LEFTMARGIN="0" MARGINHEIGHT="0" MARGINWIDTH="0">
            <FRAME src="Panelmenu.htm" LEFTMARGIN="0" MARGINHEIGHT="0" MARGINWIDTH="0" scrolling="no"
                >
            <FRAME name="fraRightFrame" src="Cuerpo.aspx" FRAMEBORDER="0" BORDER="0" BORDERCOLOR="#e1e9f6">
        </FRAMESET>
    </FRAMESET>
    <FRAME name="blanco" src="inicio.htm" scrolling="no" border="0" frameborder="no" noresize
        TOPMARGIN="0" LEFTMARGIN="0" MARGINHEIGHT="0" MARGINWIDTH="0">
</FRAMESET>
```

Ahora bien, me piden que si puedo ponerle algo responsive, entonces no se si se puede pero estaba pensando que el frame de arriba y el frame del menu izquiero lo pueda hacer responsive, el cuerpo dejarlo como esta porque son mas de 1000 aspx, entonces la pregunta sería ¿Como puedo el frame de arriba y el fram del menu izquuiero hacerlos responsive? ¿Solamente en esos dos frameset puedo aplicar bootstrap? o tal vez alguien me pueda ayudar en la idea de hacer responsive el sitio o bien aparentar un poco que es responsive.

Comment: Recomendación #1: **no uses frameset ni frames**. Se consideran obsoletos, los han quitado del estándar HTML, su uso está desaprobado y no deberían utilizarse. Aunque algunos navegadores pueden mostrarlos bien, su soporte se va a quitar y te arriesgas a que tu página deje de funcionar en cualquier momento.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que es un stio originalmente creado en VS2003 y migrado a vs2008, y la idea es modificar lo menos posible, por eso no me animo a poner masterpage u otras cosas que impliquen mucho trabajo, hay que tomar en cuenta que szon mas de 1000 formularios aspx.

Comment: si quieres implementar bootstrap de forma correcta vas a tener que planificar una restructuracion completa del sitio, quitar los frameset, usar masterpage y cambiar los mil aspx para que su contenido se adapte al layout de grid de bootstrap. Plantear lo que propones con pocos cambios no se puede, quizas debas dejarlo como esta.